# Getting error when execute maven command from powershell

Tags: ui-automation

Hi I am getting below error while running maven command from powershell

```
mvn clean install test -DsuiteXmlFile=QADesignRoomTest.xml
```

Error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------------< test:vt >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building vt 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.193 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-15T17:54:50+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".xml". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2):

Put file name in quotes:

```
mvn clean install test -DsuiteXmlFile="QADesignRoomTest.xml"
```